# Master Page background picture change

Tags: 2007, master-page, css, blog

I am creating a blog in sharepoint 2007 and i need to change the blue background that is standard on the masterpage. so far I have not been successful with this. I have read posts that say each individual class must be changed but that doesn't work. I would assume that it is one image in the background, does anybody know how I can go about doing this?

N.B. I am newbie to SharePoint and to programming in general.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the forum and I think this question has been asked before. I presume its this :) [How to change the blue background image behind the SharePoint 2007 Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23275/how-to-change-the-blue-background-image-behind-the-sharepoint-2007-page)

also this is a nice read to change the masterpage from sharepoint designer: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/modify-the-default-master-page-HA010100906.aspx

BTW I think its a css issue not a masterpage issue... below outlines what you want, above is to help you understand the consepts more ;) . ALways Always Always save the origional of anything your changing like masterpages, css, web.config..... If you make a mistake you can revert back :) .

also this will point you into the right direction into removing all the images that you dont want, including the blue background... check it out here:

**How to create a Sharepoint 2007 clear, simple and consistent theme and get rid of the default gradients**

http://hermansberghem.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/how-to-create-sharepoint-2007-clear.html

Hope it helps :)